# How to use custom docker image node:16.13.0-alpine in Codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

### summery

I tried to use docker container `node:16.13.0-alpine` in Codebuild.
However, build was failed with following error.

```
BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. 
Asm fetching username: AuthorizationData is malformed, empty field
```

I want to know how to resolve this error and build successfully passes.

### what I've tried

I set environment as follows:
[image]
In `Registry credentials` section, I added Secrets Manager ARN for Docekr credential.
[image]

### codes

Here is `buildspec.yml` for testing.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo this is test.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Registry URL was wrong.
`node:14.16.0-stretch` is successed.